# Ignore Top Bar uiwebview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am using xcode to develop an iPhone app. I have a uiwebview, that displays a website. This website has a title bar such as the one at the top of stack overflow.

I tried:

```
[webView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 50)];
```

But all that it does is move the uiwebview content farther down the screen. I was wondering how to ignore this menubar at the top.

Answer (score 1):

This will push the webview out of the screen a little bit which hides the top bar since it's out of view.

```
[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -50, width, height);
```